# Routing don't work as expected

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following route definition:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "FormPreview",
                "Forhandsgranska/{FormId}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "FormPreview", action = "Introduction", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

I have the following code that triggers the route and It works perfect:

```
  $('#previewButton').on('click', function(){
                document.location = '@Url.Action("","formPreview", new { formId = Model.Id })';
            });
```

But now I have the following code that don't work. My route definition is not triggered and I'm redirected to a wrong page, and I don't know why:

```
var formId = $(this).closest('tr').data('formId');
                        document.location = "@Url.Action("", "formPreview")/" + formId;
```

What Is the difference between these two? Why Is the first one working and not the second one?

Comment: In what way does the code "not work", error message, incorrect result, neighbour's cat sings too loudly at night?

Comment: My routing is not triggered and Im redirected wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `.replace` method.

```
document.location = '@Url.Action("", "formPreview",new {formId ="formId"})'.replace("formId",formId);
```

In Razor every content using a **@ block** is automatically HTML encoded by Razor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that don't work. Im being redirected to /formPreview/Index/31d4546d-d3e1-43cf-ba4b-1bd0e1c0bf00 instead of /Forhandsgranska/31d4546d-d3e1-43cf-ba4b-1bd0e1c0bf00

Comment: What is `Forhandsgranska` ? Your controller ?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I saw that it was id instead of formId before. Thank you :). But can you explain the difference between  document.location = "@Url.Action("", "formPreview")/" + formId; and your solution?

Comment: Because In Razor every content using a @ block is automatically HTML encoded by Razor and you have to encode entire `url`.when you write a @ with razor view engine, you are writing a instruction that will be process on the server side at the end of this command.

Comment: When you use `'@Url.Action("","formPreview", new { formId = Model.Id })'` the engine knows to encode url and recognize the route.

Comment: For more details please use `console.log()` for your `url` and you will view the difference.

Answer (score 1):

What you have specified: `@Url.Action("", "formPreview")`, is *not* the same as `@Url.Action("","formPreview", new { formId = Model.Id })`. It doesn't match because in the route table you have a *required* formId, but you haven't specified it in `@Url.Action`.

Since your URL generated by routing happens before the JavaScript has a chance to interact with it, I suppose one (hacky) way to do it would be to create a dummy formId value and replace it on the client side with a real value.

```
document.location = '@Url.Action("", "formPreview",new {formId ="DUMMY"})'.replace("DUMMY",formId);
```

### Alternative

Or you could add the dummy as a default value when the formId is not supplied.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "FormPreview",
            "Forhandsgranska/{FormId}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "FormPreview", FormId = "DUMMY", action = "Introduction", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Then you could replace the value on the client when needed.

```
document.location = '@Url.Action("", "formPreview")'.replace("DUMMY",formId);
```

However, as a side effect that means whenever you create a URL without specifying the `FormId` it will come out as `/Forhandsgranska/DUMMY`.

Comment: You provided a nice alternative . +1